# unexpected seg fault caused by lstat function

Tags: c, operating-system, filesystems

i'm making na assignment for programming class.
The program is supposed to:

1. receive a string from command line.
2. open the current directory and cycle through its entries,
   and analyse the entries only if their name starts with 
   the string that i passed from CMD.
3. if these entries are regular files,
   i need to count all characters except spaces,
   and count the number of words that start with a/A.

Here's the code.

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    if(argc!=2) //ensures at least an argument is passed.
    {
        puts("enter one argument.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    DIR* folder; //folder abstraction
    struct dirent* entry; //entry abstraction
    struct stat info; //file's i node info

    FILE* file;
    int total=0,first=0;
    char temp[100];

    int res;

    folder=opendir("."); //i open the directory

    while((entry=readdir(folder))!=NULL) //i cicle through every entry
    {

        res=strncmp(entry->d_name,argv[1],strlen(argv[1]));
        if(res==0) //if entry name begins with string i continue
        {

            lstat(entry->d_name,&info); //i take file info
            if(S_ISREG(info.st_mode)) //i check if it's a regular file
            {
                file=fopen(entry->d_name,"r"); //i open it
                //printf("%s\n",entry->d_name);
                while((fscanf(file,"%s",temp))!=EOF) //i parse it
                {
                    if(temp[0]=='a'|| temp[0]=='A')
                    {
                        first++;
                    }
                    total+=strlen(temp);
                }
                //now i close the file and print all info
                fclose(file);
                printf("%s\nthe number words that start with a/A: %i\n",entry->d_name,first);
                printf("the amount of characters except spaces is %i\n",total);
                total=0;
                first=0;
            }

        }
        //now the process will be repeated for the remaining entries
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the problem is, the program gets the first entry that starts with the pattern that i passed from CMD, evaluates it correctly, but then
when the stat is called on the second entry, it causes seg fault 11.

if i comment out the lstat, all the entries that match the criteria are recognized, even if no calculation i can't test if it's regular file without lstat...
what is causing the issue, i've been trying stuff for the past two hours, please help me, thanks!

EDIT:

I found the problem, basically the directory I'm working in has binary files of executables.

It turns out that binary files are considered regular files, so when the program opened it to parse it, it parsed one long string that caused buffer overflow on the temp variable. I thought those files were binary and separated from regular.

Comment: Aside: `while((fscanf(file,"%s",temp))!=EOF)` would be better as `while((fscanf(file,"%s",temp))==1)`

Comment: Adonai,  `char temp[100]; ... fscanf(file,"%s",temp)` is a problem with a "word" that is 100 or longer.  Also `fscanf(file...` is a problem if `file == NULL`.

Comment: @chux why it is a problem if the file is null?
btw changing buffer size didn't solve the issue,
and even if a null file was a problem, the fact is that i call the stat before i even 
open the file, so this is not the problem :/

Comment: @chux anyway, i checked if any file is null... no one is .
the seg fault happens for another reason apparently.  
enlarging buffer size doesn't even help.

Comment: The code does not check the return value from `lstat`. Error checking is paramount, especially when there are problems. A graceful program exit with a reason makes life easier during development (and more so in release versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> unexpected seg fault caused by lstat function

With undefined behavior in other parts of code, we do not know the seg fault is caused by `lstat`. Inclusion of `lstat` did reveal a problem, yet the true cause may lie elsewhere.

---

Code has troubles yet it lacks error checking in various places. [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161204/unexpected-seg-fault-caused-by-lstat-function?noredirect=1#comment93213656_53161204)

Check function return values

```
folder=opendir(".");
if (folder == NULL) {
  perror("opendir failed);
  exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}


// lstat(entry->d_name,&info);
if (lstat(entry->d_name,&info)) {
  perror("lstat failed);
  exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

file=fopen(entry->d_name,"r");
if (file == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open <%s> for reading\n", entry->d_name);
  exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Limit width

```
// while((fscanf(file,"%s",temp))!=EOF)
while(fscanf(file,"%99s",temp) == 1) {
  if (strlen(temp) == 99) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Maximum length word read, longer ones might exist\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
```

---

Of course instead of exiting, code cab handle the error in some other way.

Minor: I'd used width types for counting characters.

Comment: i checked the lstat return value before poting the question, it return 0 which means a successful execution :/ .  
it returns 0 even before seg fault :/ . 
I also enlarged the buffer to BUFSIZ which is a lot, it didn't help :/

Comment: @Adonai "i checked the lstat return value before poting" --> How did you check?  Without seeing that check (and others) properly coded, we lack evidence that the check was done right.

Comment: @Adonai A larger buffer size may help, but a check is even more important - use a width limit and then verify the buffer is large enough.

Comment: i found the problem, basically the directory i'm working in has binary files of executables.  
it turns out that binary files are considered regular files, so when the program opened it to pare it , it parsed one long string that caused buffer overflow on the temp variable... i thought those files where binary and separated from regular :(
thank you guys!

Comment: @Adonai Even with a text file, and large `temp[]`, `fscanf(file,"%s",temp)` is lingering problem.  Using a width limit with `"%s"` prevents unusual or hostile text files from seg faulting your code. It also saves you debug time.